# Is output random when using IN with LIMIT?

Tags: mysql

If I have a mysql query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4) LIMIT 2
```

Will mysql return the rows with id 1 and 2 or any 2 random id's from 1,2,3,4 from the table?

Comment: I can't speak on MySQL, but on *most* SQL products, if you don't *define* an order, the system is free to return results in any order it finds most convenient. So it would be a good habit to get into to *specify* the order you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the first two records it finds within in the `IN`, but unless you specify `order by` there is no guarantee on order. The number is fixed (number of matches from your `IN` clause limited (<=) the number specified in `LIMIT` clause ), order is not. Now generally lets say this is  your table "main"

```
ID 

1
3
2
4
```

This query

```
select * from main where id in (1,2,3,4) limit 2
```

returns

```
1
3
```

because thats how the values are in your table.It returns the order in which the data is stored(in a normal MySQL scenario). With order this becomes

```
select * from main where id in (1,2,3,4) order by id limit 2
```

returns

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your table structure, record order, and indexes so i can't predict the final results.

However, for this exact query, unless you got some strange storage engine the randomizes for fun (not any common myslq engine i know of) it will always be the first two records in the result set.  Unless you change your table structure or records, the result set should always be the same.  The query optimizer will always plan and execute the same unless indexes have changed or relative cardnality of those indexes have changed.

Answer (score 0):

It will return the first two records it finds, with ids within the interval you specified. **However**, if you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause, there is no guarantee that the items will be fetched in that particular order.